# React Native Confusion with navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

Can anyone explain to me the wrong of the word **navigate** in the below instances please

```
userByEmail(this.state.Email, navigate) // we call userByEmail ans pass email, but what does navigate do?
```

here I understand that we are kind of importing/(destructuring this.props) the method createUser from auth which is inside screenProps?? what does navigation: {navigate}} is it just the navigation props?

```
 const {screenProps: {auth: {createUser}}, navigation: {navigate}} = this.props
```

lastly what is the difference between these two

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Calendar')
navigate('Calendar')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do exactly with just some of your code. But if `navigate` is not a variable, this is wrong.

**this.props.navigation**

- When `route` is set, `navigation props` are automatically passed to the
  connected screen.
- If it is not set to route directly, the component shall be injected
  by calling the factor into the `HOC` provided by the
  `react-navigation`.

**configuring navigation props**

- navigate : go to another screen, figures out the action it needs to take to do it
- goBack - close active screen and move back in the stack
- addListener - subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle
- isFocused - function that returns true if the screen is focused and
  false otherwise.
- state - current state/routes
- setParams - make changes to route's params
- getParam - get a specific param with fallback
- dispatch - send an action to router

The `'navigate'` you want to use is a prop of `navigation`.